# public/private in C++

Tags: c++, class, c++11

I am working on a C++ project, where the lead is saying that `private/public` doesn't matter in practice, and so that all the classes should have only `public` members. Basically, he wants C++ with `struct` only.

His main argument is that huge code bases were written in C without `private`, and no bugs would have been prevented in those code bases by having a `private` keyword, so why bother?

I am countering by saying that `private` state is cleaner modularization, that it makes the code easier to reason about, easier to test, easier to refactor, that I could write assertions to make assumptions explicit with `private` state, that different teams could work independently by just agreeing on the interface of classes, but nothing seems to convince him.

What are the purely technical/objective arguments in this discussion, for/against struct/class with private members? It is a given that there is no generic answer, but I would like to list all the objective arguments I could use to evaluate which one to use in any given situation. Something like reasonable guidelines that we could all agree on, or an analysis grid that would tell us which one to use, given parameters of the situation. I would like to steer clear from personal preferences, as discussion of personal preferences is probably not productive.

It would be particularly useful to see a few concrete examples that demonstrate the pros/cons of each in specific situations.

Comment: Depends on context. There's nothing to be stated in general.

Comment: The solution will likely be a non-technical one.. Maybe http://workplace.stackexchange.com

Comment: I suppose your lead isn't a fan of [pImpl](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom).

Comment: C++ can be programmed in many styles. Wether not using private is bad or not depends on many things. But it does sound a bit suspect to have guideline saying private should not be used at all, unless it is replaced with PIMPL (then it doesn't really matter).

Comment: This is no bad question.

Comment: You can use C development practices to hide data and functions without ever using the private keyword. That's what I'd do in your place.

Answer (score 3):

My answer would be, "No, there is nothing to add."  As you said, he has already dismissed good reasons.  Maybe he's pleased with himself for recognizing that code *can* work without any private members, so he's being stubborn.  I don't know.

A struct is fine where it makes sense, but people (like me) who have maintained code extensively know that encapsulation does improve design.